# Moving ASP.NET Membership Data to Production

Tags: asp.net, membership

All,

We have a ASP.NET application working on our staging server/DB. The application works fine. We are using ASP.NET Memebership/Roles, etc.

Now it's time to deploy the application to production. As part of the deployment, we want to copy/migrate the ASP.NET Memebership database to the production servers.

Can we simply do this via SQL Server's export/import functions? Will the applications IDs and role IDs that move to the production DB make sense when the ASP.NET application is deployed on the new boxes?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine.  The IDs are all for internal storage, so no issue.  Just make sure the config matches and you are good

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com)'s SQL Data Compare as a more robust (configurable) solution to moving data between databases.  I think you'd probably be ok doing a simple export/import, but you'd need to be careful of autogenerate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Database Publishing Wizard from within Visual Studio?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vssetup/thread/42bbad47-5b6e-4e99-8d27-07bcbd123064

Everything should work fine on the production server.